# R - group_by & summarise as list - display data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

**Edit: Sorry, I just realised I missed adding some info; There are multiple `value` cols**

I'm trying to `group_by` a `data.frame` and `summarise` the values as lists. However, I also want to add additional information to the list.

Here's what I have tried and what I would like to achieve.

```
    df <- 
  data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01",
                    "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"),
           company = c("A", "B", "C",
                       "A", "B", "C"),
           product = c("P1", "P1", "P2",
                       "P1", "P2", "P2"),
           value_1 = c(1,1,2,
                     2,3,4),
           value_2 = c(5,6,8,
                       9,1,3),
           stringsAsFactors = F) %>% as_tibble() 
df_sum <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(date, product) %>% summarise_if(.predicate = is.numeric, .funs = function(x) list(x))
```

Instead of just showing the values in `df_sum` I would like to add respective company. I.e., `df_sum$value_1[[2]]` should return something like

```
  company value
1       B     3
2       C     4
```

instead of

```
[1] 3 4
```

and `df_sum$value_2[[2]]`

```
 company value_2
1       B       1
2       C       3
```

Just like Cettts answer, with the ability to show multiple cols

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  date       product value_1          value_2       
  <chr>      <chr>   <list>           <list> 
1 2020-01-01 P1      <tibble [2 x 2]> <tibble [2 x 2]>
2 2020-01-01 P2      <tibble [1 x 2]> <tibble [1 x 2]>
3 2019-01-01 P1      <tibble [1 x 2]> <tibble [1 x 2]>
4 2019-01-01 P2      <tibble [2 x 2]> <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `nest` from the `tidyr` package for this:

```
df %>%
   tidyr::nest(value = c(company, value))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  date       product value           
  <chr>      <chr>   <list>          
1 2020-01-01 P1      <tibble [2 x 2]>
2 2020-01-01 P2      <tibble [1 x 2]>
3 2019-01-01 P1      <tibble [1 x 2]>
4 2019-01-01 P2      <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

This returns a nested dataframe (or nested tibble to be more precise).

#### EDIT

Here is a solution for multiple value columns:

```
df_sum <- df %>%
   nest(value_1 = c(company, value_1), 
        value_2 = c(company, value_2))
```

Comment: Exactly like that. Except that I forgot to add that there are multiple value cols, please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to apply to an arbitrary number of values?

Comment: not to my knowledge.
But if you have multimple columns you maybe should consider switching to a different data format: it makes no sense to duplicate the company column.